# python file.write() does not create new line

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am new to Python and am following a tutorial on how to write/read text files [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_files_io.htm).  But I ran into an issue where when writing a file, it does not create another line, but just writes directly after the first one.  I attached my code below, any help is appreciated greatly!

```
   import os
import sys
def generate_cdat():
    file = open("documents/pytho/login/cdat.txt", "w")
    file.write("username[usr]")
    file.write("userpass[1234]")
    file.close()
def getCredentials(checkUsrName, checkUsrPass):
    file = open("documents/pytho/login/cdat.txt", "r")
    recievedUsrName = file.readline(1)
    recievedUsrPass = file.readline(2)
    if checkUsrName in recievedUsrPass:
        print("recieved username")
print("started program")
print("checking for constant data file")
path = "cdat.txt"
if os.path.exists(path):
    print("Constant data found, setting up")
else:
    print("Constant data not found, creating constant data.")
    generate_cdat()
print("starting login")
logingIn = True
while logingIn == True:
    getUsrName = input("Enter username: ")
    getUsrPass = getpass.getpass("Enter password: ")
    checkCredentials(getUsrName, getUsrPass)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding \n at the end of the string

Comment: That worked!  Thanks for the help, that was kind of stupid.